# Webgl json object show strange texture when rendered

Tags: json, textures, webgl

I have modelled a curling stone in blender with UV coordinates. In blender it looks like this, with the 3D view and UV/image editor up:

http://imgur.com/2q8YfvI&B26eaHG&V3NaMNQ#2

I have then exported it as a waveFront (.obj) format and used a c++ script from semisignal.com to convert it to json-format

When loading the json object to my webGL project it shows up with a disfigured texture, I wonder if this is common problem and someone could point to where the problem lies (in blender/ the convertion to json/ or the webGL code?), or maybe it is impossible to tell from just this?

http://imgur.com/2q8YfvI&B26eaHG&V3NaMNQ#0

this is is the loadtexture function i am using if it is relevant:

```
function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

var stone_texture;

function initTextures() {
    neheTexture = gl.createTexture();
    neheTexture.image = new Image();
    neheTexture.image.onload = function () {
        handleLoadedTexture(stone_texture)
    }

    neheTexture.image.src = "stone_texture.png";
}
```

Comment: To me it looks like the 3d model is what is being rendered incorrectly and not the texture.

Comment: thank you, that narrowed it down! when removing the texture and just use color it still comes out weird.

Comment: Try another exporter, that should not be happening when you remove the texture. If you are able to work with three.js json models: https://github.com/zfedoran/convert-to-threejs-json

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for your help, you guys pointed me in the right direction. It was the obj to json converter from semisignal that wasnt working correctly. I switched to another and it rendered just fine.